# Run javascript in each Django for loop?

Tags: javascript, python, django, for-loop

I have a Javascript function that converts markdown to html:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        editormd.markdownToHTML("content", {
            //htmlDecode      : "style,script,iframe",  // you can filter tags decode
            emoji           : true,
            taskList        : true,
            tex             : true,
            flowChart       : true,
            sequenceDiagram : true,
        });
  
        $(".reference-link").each(function (i,obj) {
          console.log(obj)
        })
    })
  
  </script>
```

But when I run this in a for loop the Javascript only runs on the **first** post.

```
{% for entry in entry_list %}
<div id="content"><textarea>{{ entry.content|truncatechars_html:180 }}</textarea></div>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I make it run on each loop?

Comment: If you're re-using the same `id` in your markup then the markup is invalid.  What is `editormd.markdownToHTML`?  Does it *need* an `id` or can it use a different selector?

Comment: Sorry ’m not too familiar with JavaScript, what would be a better selector to use other than ID?

Comment: A class selector would likely be preferred here.  Then you could re-use the same `class` value in your `<div>` instead of the same `id` value.